# Hibernate relationship mapping not bidirecional

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I want to create an hibernate relationship between entities but not bidireccional, and I would like to know what is the best approach. In the case of one to one I see here and other blogs that people use the id of the external entity with the primary_key of the dependency entity.
For one to many let say that I have entity A and entity B and I want that A know B but not bidireccional, in that case I would add the id of A in a column of B and I would add the hibernate relationship on A right?. The problem about this is that looks like Hibernate cannot make this relationship if in B I dont mention the relationship with A.

Somebody here can give me a hint about it.

Best regards.

Comment: If you're having trouble, start from the data model and not from the entity hierarchy. How would you normally create the table structure if you'd just be using pure SQL? Once you have that, create your entities to match that data model. Not having a bidirectional mapping should actually be easier to create than having one.

Comment: Hibernate has a reference documentation with examples of every possible association mapping. Read it.

Answer (score 1):

Any JPA implementation (and Hibernate of course) supports:

- unidirectional
- bidirectional

relationship (associations) for entities.

Further, there are following kinds of associations:

- one-to-one
- one-to-many
- many-to-one
- many-to-many.

You should choose which one to use. [Description](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Relationships#JPA_Relationship_Types).

After that, you should choose which mapping method will you use:

- hibernate XML (legacy)
- JPA2 annotations

[Hibernate XML examples](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/manual/en-US/html_single/#associations).

[JPA2 ManyToOne example](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ManyToOne) (see other pages, it is a book)